# How get conditional count while using group by in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql newbie here.

I have a table( name:'audit_webservice_aua' ) like this:

```
+---------+------------------------------------+-------------------+------------------------+
| auditId |          device_code               |   response_status |       request_date
+---------+------------------------------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|   10001 | 0007756-gyy66-4c6e-a59d-xxxccyyyt1 |       P           | 2020-03-02 00:00:08.785
|   10002 | 0007756-gyy66-4c6e-a59d-xxxccyyyt2 |       F           | 2020-04-06 00:00:08.785
|   10003 | 0007756-gyy66-4c6e-a59d-xxxccyyyt3 |       F           | 2020-04-01 00:01:08.785
|   10004 | 0007756-gyy66-4c6e-a59d-xxxccyyyt1 |       P           | 2020-05-02 00:02:08.785
|   10005 | 0007756-gyy66-4c6e-a59d-xxxccyyyt1 |       P           | 2020-05-09 00:03:08.785
|   10006 | 0007756-gyy66-4c6e-a59d-xxxccyyyt2 |       P           | 2020-05-09 01:00:08.785
|   10007 | 0007756-gyy66-4c6e-a59d-xxxccyyyt7 |       F           | 2020-06-06 02:00:08.785
+---------+------------------------------------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

Every time a new request is made the above table stores the requesting device_code ,response_status and request time.

I have a requirement of getting the result set which contains the each device_code, total_trans, total_successful, total_failure and date for each day between two given dates.

The query i have written is as follows:

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aua.request_date,'%b') as month , 
    YEAR(aua.request_date) as year,
     DATE_FORMAT(aua.request_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
    (select count(aua.audit_id) )as total_trans ,
    (select count(aua.audit_id) where aua.response_status  'P') as total_failure ,
    (select count(aua.audit_id) where aua.response_status = 'P') as total_successful ,
    aua.device_code as deviceCode
    FROM audit_webservice_aua aua where DATE_FORMAT(aua.request_date,'%Y-%m-%d') between '2020-04-16' and '2020-07-17' 
    group by dates,deviceCode ;
```

In the above code im tring to get results between '2020-03-02' and '2020-06-06' but the count im getting is not correct.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(aua.request_date,'%b') as month , 
       YEAR(aua.request_date) as year,
       DATE_FORMAT(aua.request_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
       COUNT(aua.audit_id) as total_trans ,
       SUM(aua.response_status <> 'P') as total_failure,
       SUM(aua.response_status = 'P') as total_successful,
       aua.device_code as deviceCode
FROM audit_webservice_aua aua 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(aua.request_date, '%Y-%m-%d') between '2020-04-16' and '2020-07-17' 
GROUP BY month, year, date, deviceCode ;
```

I would also advise you to change the `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE aua.request_date >= '2020-04-16' AND
      aua.request_date >= '2020-07-18'
```